# JBOSS EAP Folder Structure - confused between EAP 7.3 and JBoss-AS

Tags: jboss

I am new to J2EE development. I installed EAP 7.3 from internet (version.txt file has the information "Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform - Version 7.3.0.GA"). I see a different directory structure than what is mentioned at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/5/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/server_directory_structure
Was the above link for version 5 and JBoss has completely changed its folder structure in 7.x? I see the followings folders under my top-level folder - .installation, .well-known, appclient, bin, docs, domain, icons, installation, migration, modules, standalone, uninstaller, welcome-content etc.
Is CLI/ Management console the only option to define DataSource etc. OR have I installed something wrong?

Comment: You can define it in standalone.xml and yes JBoss EAP 7 is completely different than 5

Comment: CLI or the management console are the best ways to configure the server.